# Are there any reporting solutions that work on Linux?

Tags: sql, linux, reporting-services, reporting

Question:

I need a equivalent of Microsoft Reporting Service, that works on Linux.
Free or for cash. Of course preferably free.

Requirements:

```
WYSIWYG Report Editor (for developer, don't care if that part only works on windows)
Ability to dynamically generate reports from the web
Usage of one or multiple database types (like MySQL, PostGre, Oracle, ODBC)
multiple file formats support (including HTML)
support for graphs/charts
scalable
```

What are the possiblilities ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eclipse BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/)

Comment: Or JasperSoft Reports (TIBCO) - much better performance than BIRT.